# Validate data in 2 columns against master table one column spark.sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyspark

I have 2 table, say master table for ZIPCODE, and a transaction table which contains current address & Permanent address.  Both address columns will have ZIPCODE.  I need to validate these 2 zip codes against the master table.

```
Master Table:
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|zip_code|territory_name|state| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A02| TERR NAME 02| NY| 
| 81A04| TERR NAME 04| FL| 
| 81A05| TERR NAME 05| NJ| 
| 81A06| TERR NAME 06| CA| 
| 81A07| TERR NAME 06| CA|
+--------+--------------+-----+

Transaction table:
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
|Address1_zc|Address2_zc|state| 
+--------+--------------+-----+ 
| 81A02| 81A05| NY| 
| 81A04| 81A06| FL| 
| 81A05| 90005| NJ| 
| 81A06| 90006| CA| 
| 41A06| 81A06| CA|
+--------+--------------+-----+
```

The result set should contain only the valid zip codes in both ADDRESS1_ZC & ADDRESS2_ZC.

```
 +-----------+-----------+-----+ 
 |Address1_zc|Address2_zc|state| 
 +-----------+-----------+-----+ 
 | 81A02     | 81A05     | NY  | 
 | 81A04     | 81A06     | FL  | 
 +-----------+-----------+-----+
```

For testing am providing herewith dataframe:

```
df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","CA"),("81A02","TERR NAME 02","NY"),("81A03","TERR NAME 03","NY"), ("81A03","TERR NAME 03","CA"), ("81A04","TERR NAME 04","FL"), ("81A05","TERR NAME 05","NJ"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA")], ["zip_code","territory_name","state"])
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1_mast")

df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A02","81A05"),("81A04","81A06"),("81A05","90005"),("81A06","90006"),("41A06","81A06")], ["Address1_zc","Address2_zc"])
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1_tran")
```

I tried the following SQL but am unable to get the desired result.

```
select a.* df1_tran a join df1_mast b on a.zip_code = b.Address_zc1 or a.zip_code = b.Address_zc2 where a.zip_code is null
```

Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand where your `81A05` and `81A06` come from in `Address2_zc` in the 3rd dataframe

Comment: Does it work if you replace `or` with `and`?

Comment: Peirre Gourseaud, i have updated dataset, can you please take a look. Thanks

Comment: no it didnt work even if replacing OR with AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark way :

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ"),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","CA"),("81A02","TERR NAME 02","NY"),("81A03","TERR NAME 03","NY"), ("81A03","TERR NAME 03","CA"), ("81A04","TERR NAME 04","FL"), ("81A05","TERR NAME 05","NJ"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA"), ("81A06","TERR NAME 06","CA")], ["zip_code","territory_name","state"])

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A02","81A05"),("81A04","81A06"),("81A05","90005"),("81A05","90006"),("41A06","81A06")], ["Address1_zc","Address2_zc"])

df3 = df2.join(df1, df2['Address1_zc'] == df1['zip_code'], 'inner')
df4 = df3.withColumnRenamed('state', 'state1').drop(*(df1.columns))
df5 = df4.join(df1, df2['Address2_zc'] == df1['zip_code'], 'inner')
df6 = df5.withColumnRenamed('state', 'state2').drop(*(df1.columns))
df4.show()

 +-----------+-----------+------+------+
 |Address1_zc|Address2_zc|state1|state2|
 +-----------+-----------+------+------+
 | 81A02     | 81A05     |NY    |NJ    |
 | 81A04     | 81A06     |FL    |CA    |
 +-----------+-----------+------+------+
```

SQL way :

```
SELECT t.*,
       a.state AS state1, 
       b.state AS state2
FROM df2 AS t
       JOIN df1 AS a ON t.Address1_zc = a.zip_code      
       JOIN df1 AS b ON t.Address2_zc = b.zip_code
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide this in spark.sql JOIN format, since I cannot use python way in my project.

Comment: @Yuva I added the SQL syntax